# Trying to create a delete link_to for nested_attributes object in its parents view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-attributes

So I have a situation were users are owned by accounts.

I am listing users for each account as follows:

```
for @user in @account.users.where(['email <> ?', 'null']).sort! {|b, a| a.id <=> b.id}
```

For each user I want to be able to offer the functionality to delete via a link. I have the following:

```
<p>Are you sure you want to delete <%=h @user.firstname %>?:
<%= link_to "Yes", account_users_path(@user), :remote => true, :method => :delete, :class => "button" %>
<span class="button canceldeleteobject"> No </span></p>
```

However, when I run this I get:

```
Started DELETE "/accounts/28/users" for ::1 at 2012-03-29 09:42:39 -0400

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action '28' could not be found for AccountsController):
```

The user id is '28' where as the account id is '15', therefore I sense it has something to do with the account_users_path element, but any light you could shed on the best way to do this type of nested_attribute delete would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Routes look like this:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }, :skip => :registrations do
    get 'users/edit' => 'registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
    put 'users' => 'registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
    delete 'users' => 'registrations#destroy', :as => 'destroy_user_registration'    
  end

  resources :accounts do
    resources :assessments, :areas, :risks, :controls, :persons, :roles, :mitigations, :comments, :users
    collection do
      put :update_attribute_on_the_spot
      get :get_attribute_on_the_spot
    end
  end
```

Comment: What does your `routes.rb` file look like for `:accounts` and `:users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `account_user_path(@account, @user)` instead (you had pluralized `users`, and didn't include the parent `account`).

Comment: Thanks Dylan - spot on answer.